# Extract the extension and save image names in array

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray

I have few images in the "ProjectImages" folder and wanted to retrieve the image file name from the above folder and store it in array and then i wanted to extract the extension of those images files and store it in another array. I'm able to retrieve the image file names from the folder and extract the extension, but i don't know how to store the extracted file name in another array. Below is the code

```
//get image name from the folder
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *directory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProjectImages"];

    NSArray *files=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];

//extract the extension
NSString *imageNames=nil;
    for (NSString *name in files) {
        if (!imageNames) imageNames = [[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        else imageNames = [imageNames stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",[[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

    }
NSLog(@"%@",imageNames); --> This returns one single name with all the image name, which i don't want, instead i want to store each extracted file name in array and wanted to compare the string entered by the user with this array. how to do it ?
```

Comment: You're not storing anything in any array. You're building a space delimited string of filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You are not storing image name in array
 Try this way


    //get image name from the folder
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *directory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProjectImages"];
    NSArray *files=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];
    //extract the extension
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *name in files) {
        NSString imageName = [[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
if ([array indexOfObject:imageName inRange:NSMakeRang(0,[array count])]!=NSNotFound){ 
//duplicate
 }
else
 {
 [array addObject:imageName];
 }

}
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: Thank you shashi3456643 ! and i used if ([array containsObject:user_entered_string]) to compare if the user entered string is there in the mutablearray, but it didn;t give any result. below is the code
for (NSString *name in files) {
        NSString *imageName = [[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        [imgaftext addObject:imageName];
        if ([imgaftext containsObject:message]) { //message is the string entered by the user
            NSLog(@"Yes");
        }
        
    }

Comment: You are saying yo don't to add duplicate if already exists then don't add you can use inRange.

Comment: if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRang(0,[mutableArray count])]!=NSNotFound){ //duplicate }

Comment: Thanks for the reply shashi...above posted code worked..."message" returned different string, so it failed to compare..i had to trim few characters..after trimming, it worked...thanks again